# What easing function does Google Chrome v8 use for scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, easing

What easing function does Google Chrome v8 implement for

```js
window.scrollTo({ x, y }, { behavior: "smooth" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome (V8) uses an [EaseInOut animation](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:cc/animation/scroll_offset_animation_curve_factory.cc;l=40;drc=c77ccde5b729af314595e528d89837d2c890f94f;bpv=1;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) with a [delta-based duration](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:cc/animation/scroll_offset_animation_curve.cc;l=184;drc=c77ccde5b729af314595e528d89837d2c890f94f;bpv=1;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) over a [cubic-bezier timing function](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:cc/animation/scroll_offset_animation_curve.cc;l=143;drc=c77ccde5b729af314595e528d89837d2c890f94f;bpv=1;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) ([here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:ui/gfx/geometry/cubic_bezier.h;drc=c77ccde5b729af314595e528d89837d2c890f94f;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=15?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) is the implementation in Chrome, and [here](https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing) is an MIT-licensed implementation) parametrized with [these arguments](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:cc/animation/timing_function.cc;l=36;bpv=1;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F).

Comment: For the record, V8 has nothing to do with this; this is all Chrome code.